# ffprobe reports different format depending on file extension

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffprobe on Windows to identify files.  The command/parameters I use are:

ffprobe -show_entries format=format_name -v quiet filename

I noticed with certain image files ffprobe reports a different format if the file name has (or does not have) and extension.  For example, for a BMP image file named XXX

`ffprobe -show_entries format=format_name -v quiet XXX`

reports

`[FORMAT]
format_name=mp3
[/FORMAT]`

But, if I rename the file to XXX.BMP and rerun the command

`ffprobe -show_entries format=format_name -v quiet XXX.BMP`

reports

`[FORMAT]
format_name=image2
[/FORMAT]`

Is this behavior expected?  Has anyone else encountered this issue?  I am using the most recent version of ffmpeg.

Comment: does ffmpeg do the same thing? (ffmpeg -i input_filename)?

Comment: Thanks, ffpmpeg reports the following on the file without the extension: [mp3 @ 0000000002077a40] Format mp3 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!  Seems like ffmpeg uses the extension to help figure out the format.